# Switch Statement only executing Case 1-Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend

My Switch Statement is only executing the first case. I've included breaks at the appropriate sections, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm trying to grab the current date and compare that date to the form date and delete that form option if its before the current date. I've been able to use a simple if else statement successfully to accomplish this, but I thought a switch statement would be faster.

All help is appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bpf8J/2/

JS

```
var checkapril1 = new Date();
checkapril1.setFullYear(2013, 3, 3);

var checkapril2 = new Date();
checkapril2.setFullYear(2013, 3, 17);

var checkmay1 = new Date();
checkmay1.setFullYear(2013, 4, 1);

var checkmay2 = new Date();
checkmay2.setFullYear(2013, 4, 15);

var checkmay3 = new Date();
checkmay3.setFullYear(2013, 4, 29);

var checkjune1 = new Date();
checkjune1.setFullYear(2013, 5, 12);

var checkjune2 = new Date();
checkjune2.setFullYear(2013, 5, 26);

var todaydate = new Date();
var e = document.getElementById("EventDate");

switch (true) {
case checkapril1 < todaydate:
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++)
    var things = e.options[1];
    things.style.display = "none";
    things.disabled = true;
    break;

case checkapril2 < todaydate:
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++)
    var things = e.options[2];
    things.style.display = "none";
    things.disabled = true;
    break;


case checkmay1 < todaydate:
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++)
    var things = e.options[3];
    things.style.display = "none";
    things.disabled = true;
    break;


case checkmay2 < todaydate:
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++)
    var things = e.options[4];
    things.style.display = "none";
    things.disabled = true;
    break;

case checkmay3 < todaydate:
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++)
    var things = e.options[5];
    things.style.display = "none";
    things.disabled = true;
    break;

case checkjune1 < todaydate:
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++)
    var things = e.options[6];
    things.style.display = "none";
    things.disabled = true;
    break;


case checkjune2 < todaydate:
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++)
    var things = e.options[7];
    things.style.display = "none";
    things.disabled = true;
    break;
```

}

HTML

```
<form class="lpeRegForm formNotEmpty" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-      urlencoded" action="http://info.kinnser.com/index.php/leadCapture/save" id="mktForm_145"     name="mktForm_145">
<ul class='mktLblLeft'>
    <li class='mktFormReq mktField'>
            <label>EVENT DATE:</label><span class='mktInput'><select class='mktFormSelect mktFReq' name="EventDate" id="EventDate" size='1'   tabIndex='1'><option value='' selected='selected'>Please Select...</option><option value='April 3 2013'>April 3 2013</option><option value='April 17'>April 17 2013</option><option value='May 1'>May 1 2013</option><option value='May 15'>May 15 2013</option><option value='May 29'>May 29 2013</option><option value='June 12'>June 12 2013</option><option value='June 26'>June 26 2013</option></select><span class='mktFormMsg'></span></span>
    </li>
    <li class='mktFormReq mktField'>
        <label>First Name:</label><span class='mktInput'><input class='mktFormText mktFormString mktFReq' name="FirstName" id="FirstName" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='2' /><span class='mktFormMsg'></span></span>
    </li>
    <li class='mktFormReq mktField'>
        <label>Last Name:</label><span class='mktInput'><input class='mktFormText mktFormString mktFReq' name="LastName" id="LastName" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='3' /><span class='mktFormMsg'></span></span>
    </li>
    <li class='mktFormReq mktField'>
        <label>Agency Name:</label><span class='mktInput'><input class='mktFormText mktFormString mktFReq' name="Company" id="Company" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='4' /><span class='mktFormMsg'></span></span>
    </li>
    <li class='mktFormReq mktField'>
        <label>Email Address:</label><span class='mktInput'><input class='mktFormText mktFormEmail mktFReq' name="Email" id="Email" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='5' /><span class='mktFormMsg'></span></span>
    </li>
    <li class='mktFormReq mktField'>
        <label>Zip Code:</label><span class='mktInput'><input class='mktFormText mktFormString mktFReq' name="PostalCode" id="PostalCode" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='6' /><span class='mktFormMsg'></span></span>
    </li>
    <li class='mktFormReq mktField'>
        <label>Phone Number:</label><span class='mktInput'><input class='mktFormText mktFormPhone mktFReq' name="Phone" id="Phone" type='text' value=""  maxlength='255' tabIndex='7' /><span class='mktFormMsg'></span></span>
    </li>
    <li class='mktFormReq mktField'>
        <label>Role:</label><span class='mktInput'><select class='mktFormSelect mktFReq' name="Role__c" id="Role__c" size='1'   tabIndex='8'><option value='' selected='selected'>Please Select...</option><option value='Administrator'>Administrator</option><option value='Billing'>Billing</option><option value='CEO'>CEO</option><option value='CFO'>CFO</option><option value='Clinician'>Clinician</option><option value='Consultant'>Consultant</option><option value='D.O.N.'>D.O.N.</option><option value='Director of Operations (DOO)'>Director of Operations (DOO)</option><option value='I.T.'>I.T.</option><option value='Other'>Other</option><option value='Owner'>Owner</option><option value='Q.A.'>Q.A.</option><option value='Therapist'>Therapist</option></select><span class='mktFormMsg'></span></span>
    </li>
    <li class='mktFormReq mktField'>
        <label>Medicare Census:</label><span class='mktInput'><select class='mktFormSelect mktFReq' name="Agency_Census_Range__c_account" id="Agency_Census_Range__c_account" size='1'   tabIndex='9'><option value='' selected='selected'>Please Select...</option><option value='0 - 50'>0 - 50</option><option value='51 - 125'>51 - 125</option><option value='126 - 250'>126 - 250</option><option value='251 - 500'>251 - 500</option><option value='501-750'>501-750</option><option value='751-1000'>751-1000</option><option value='1001+'>1001+</option></select><span class='mktFormMsg'></span></span>
    </li>
    <li class='mktField' style="display: none;">
        <label>Lead Source:</label><span class='mktInput'><input class='mktFormHidden' name="LeadSource" id="LeadSource" type='hidden' value="Product Tour" /><span class='mktFormMsg'></span></span>
    </li>
    <li class='mktField' style="display: none;">
        <label>Referral Code:</label><span class='mktInput'><input class='mktFormHidden' name="Event_Ref_Source__c" id="Event_Ref_Source__c" type='hidden' value="Product Tour" /><span class='mktFormMsg'></span></span>
    </li>
    <li class='mktField' style="display: none;">
        <label>OfferID:</label><span class='mktInput'><input class='mktFormHidden' name="OfferID" id="OfferID" type='hidden' value="" /><span class='mktFormMsg'></span></span>
    </li>
    <li class='mktField mktLblRight'><span class='mktInput mktLblRight'><input class='mktFormCheckbox' name="SalesMeetingRequest" id="SalesMeetingRequest" type='checkbox' value="1"   tabIndex='13' /><label>Yes, I want to speak to a Kinnser Software solutions expert.</label>&nbsp;<span class='mktFormMsg'></span></span>
    </li>
    <li id='mktFrmButtons'>
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input id='mktFrmSubmit' type='submit' style="width: auto; overflow: visible; padding-left: .25em; padding-right: .25em;" value='Register Now' name='submitButton' onclick='formSubmit(document.getElementById("mktForm_145")); return false;' />&nbsp;
        <input style='display: none;' id='mktFrmReset' type='reset' value='Clear' name='resetButton' onclick='formReset(document.getElementById("mktForm_145")); return false;' />
    </li>
</ul> <span style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="_marketo_comments" value="" /></span>

<input type="hidden" name="lpId" value="1811" />
<input type="hidden" name="subId" value="26" />
<input type="hidden" name="munchkinId" value="010-FKU-440" />
<input type="hidden" name="kw" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="cr" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="searchstr" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="lpurl" value="http://info.kinnser.com/2013ProductTour.html?cr={creative}&kw={keyword}" />
<input type="hidden" name="formid" value="145" />
<input type="hidden" name="returnURL" value="http://info.kinnser.com/2013ProductTourThanks.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="retURL" value="http://info.kinnser.com/2013ProductTourThanks.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="returnLPId" value="1812" />
<input type="hidden" name="_mkt_disp" value="return" />
<input type="hidden" name="_mkt_trk" value="id:010-FKU-440&token:_mch-kinnser.com-1363892390400-55419" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how JavaScript `switch` statements work. The values on the `case` statements are evaluated statically.  You need a sequence of `if ... else` clauses.

Also, your logic looks backwards to me. You check the dates in increasing order, starting from the smallest. Thus a date that's in July will satisfy the very first test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the for loops you have are supposed to do, but I don't think that's what you intended. If you have, say:

```
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++)
    var things = e.options[1];
    things.style.display = "none";
    things.disabled = true;
```

Then only the first line will be executed; you need to wrap them in a block using { }.

```
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++)
{
    var things = e.options[1];
    things.style.display = "none";
    things.disabled = true;
}
```

Also as Pointy mentioned, a switch is not the proper tool for this job. Switch statements branch based on discrete values of a variable, like:

```
switch(food)
{
    case 'apple':
        eat();
        break;

    case 'poison':
        donteat();
        break;
}
```

You should put those dates in an array or something, that way it'll be easier if you need to add new dates. Getting to answering your question though, I think I understand what you want to do; try something like this:

**JavaScript**

```
var check = [
    new Date(2013, 3, 3),
    new Date(2013, 3, 17),
    new Date(2013, 4, 1),
    new Date(2013, 4, 15),
    new Date(2013, 4, 29),
    new Date(2013, 5, 12),
    new Date(2013, 5, 26)
];

var todaydate = new Date();
var e = document.getElementById("EventDate");

for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++)
{
    if (check[i] < todaydate)
    {
        var things = e.options[i];
            things.style.display = "none";
            things.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

What this code is doing is placing the dates in an array and looping through them. Each time, if the date is before the current date, it will find the option element and disable it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bpf8J/12/